# flutter bloc and how a bloc state change can then trigger a 2nd async call before updating the Widget/UI with both? (code attached)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, dart-async

How would one load a set of local images for display in a widget (noting this is async - see function below) triggered by (based on) a change in state from a flutter_bloc for “settings”?  Noting this bloc is persisted too via hydrated_bloc.  So the use case for which I’m asking how do I code this in flutter (noting I’m using flutter_bloc) is:

Use Case - Render different set of images on the same Widget I have for dynamically displaying a room for a 2D point & click adventure type game, BASED ON the “room” the user goes to.  A change in room event is passed to a SettingsBloc which will then determine the new “room” to move to.  This new “room” state is available via the Bloc concept, however how & where do I then do the async load of the specific set of images I need for this room (nothing they are set at compile time)?  (To feed it to the dynamic room rendering widget with a CustomPainter that I have - i.e. images painted onto canvas).

For example which approach is recommended to do this? (then ideally what the code looks like to achive this)

a) Listen for a change in “room” within the widget, and then trigger (within a widget) to call the async function to dynamically load the  ui.Image’s that I need?  But if yes, how do you do this in code within a Widget? (or is this not best practice). Refer my code below which does work/run but seems to have a infinite loop happening  OR

b) Should I setup Images as a separate bloc (e.g. images_bloc).  But in this case what is the flutter code that would be required to do this:  i.e.

- user does something in UI that triggers an event & passes it to SettingsBloc
- the SettingsBloc then may determine there is a change in "room" due to this and change/emit the new "currentRoom"
- the SettingsBloc would then then to trigger an aynch request to ImagesBlock (somehow) get the new List of ui.Images for this "room", using the async code below
- The UI/Widget then needs to pickup the changes for “String room” and List of ui.Image’s

c) Another approach?

---

Here is my best try at approach (a) above so far.  Works in UI re changing background, however there seems to be an infinite loop:

Logging:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           29.5s
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:49364/lyUIDblZgmY=/ws
flutter: game_main.build ----------------------------
flutter: trying to get room data for current room: room2
flutter: About to load imagename:plane.png
flutter: game_main.build ----------------------------
flutter: trying to get room data for current room: room2
flutter: About to load imagename:plane.png
flutter: game_main.build ----------------------------
flutter: trying to get room data for current room: room2
flutter: About to load imagename:plane.png
flutter: game_main.build ----------------------------
ETC ETC
```

Code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:adventure/ui/widgets/game_painter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:adventure/bloc/settings_cubit.dart';
import 'package:adventure/game_design/room.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:touchable/touchable.dart';

class GameMain extends StatefulWidget {
  GameMain({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _GameMainState createState() => _GameMainState();
}

class _GameMainState extends State<GameMain> {
  final RoomsData roomsData = RoomsData.getPopulated();
  ui.Image _backgroundImage;

  Future<ui.Image> _loadImageAsync(imageString) async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(imageString);
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
    return image;
  }

  Future<void> _updateBackgroundImageState(String imagename) async {
    print('About to load imagename:$imagename');
    final image = await _loadImageAsync('assets/images/$imagename');
    setState(() {
      _backgroundImage = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('game_main.build ----------------------------');

    // Get Persistant Data Settings 
    SettingsCubit settingsCubit = context.watch<SettingsCubit>();

    // Get Room Configuration (for room we're now in)
    print('Trying to get room data for current room: ${settingsCubit.state.currentRoom}');
    Room roomData = roomsData.getRoom(settingsCubit.state.currentRoom);

    // Update Background Image
    _updateBackgroundImageState(roomData.backgroundImage);
    
    // Create and return Canvas
    return Container(
      child: BlocBuilder<SettingsCubit, SettingsState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Stack(children: <Widget>[

            CanvasTouchDetector(
              builder: (context) => CustomPaint(
                painter: GamePainter(context, settingsCubit, roomData, _backgroundImage)
              )
            ),

            FlatButton(
              // For testing changes to background image
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                var newRoomString = settingsCubit.state.currentRoom == 'room1' ? 'room2' : 'room1';
                settingsCubit.setRoom(newRoomString);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Flat Button",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),

          ]);
        }
      )
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: i am a lot confused by your solution you call a function in the build function that changes the state which will call build again so for sure it is infinite loop, a solution would be that you should listen to the future using futurebuilder Widget and show a loading indicator until the image loads

Comment: I am not sure if I got what you need right or not but hope it helps, and in case of the image changes multiple times then create a stream and listen to the changes using streambuilder , if it isn't clear let me know I will show you a code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of yours code is that you put the **setStatus inside build**, so it call *build -> _updateBackgroundImage -> setStatus -> rebuild -> _updateBackgroundImage  ... (infinite)*

I think the date update flow looks like:

```
change SettingsCubit -> get RoomData ->  (wait for async image data) -> _updateBackgroundImage
```

### The point is what do you want to show if the image is still in loading?

The answers may be like:

1. Change background/room until the image loaded
2. Show Loading Indicator
3. Show sync data first, and change the background later

The last two can be done easily with [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). But for bloc concept, you can add new state inside **SettingsCubit** and control the image state when loading

```
class SettingsCubit extends Cubit{
  ...
  Future setRoom(String newRoom) async {
    // emit state (imageIsLoading = true)
    // load image async func
    // emit state (imageIsLoading = false, image data update in state)
  }
}
...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SettingsCubit settingsCubit = context.watch<SettingsCubit>();

  if(settingsCubit.state.imageIsLoading){
    // show what do you want to show when image is not ready
  }else{
    // show room with image (ex. from settingsCubit.state.imageData)
  }
```

Of course you can add new bloc like **ImagesBloc** for more structured code.

Comment: thanks - let me try - so effectively using Bloc/Cubit to store both (a) some state that needs to be persisted like the last room the user was in as well as (b) some ephemeral state [is image loaded] then?   I guess I was trying to keep the ephemeral state in the widget..

Comment: also if using cubit for state for images loaded, if there are several on a screen would you recommend one dedicated image cubit/bloc for  room/screens worth of images?  i.e. so state is loaded only when all loaded then?  and not mix other data like which room the user is in in that cubit/bloc?

Comment: I think yes because the SettingsCubit is not like a cubit name which contains the image data. Also you can make the `widgets need to be rebuilt` as small as possible, making some part only listen to ImagesBloc.